# $date format("M y") always showing the wrong month (the one before)

Tags: php, date

I got this code:

```
list($year, $month, $day) = explode("-", $row['game_release']);
    if (checkdate($month, $day, $year)) {
       $date = (new DateTime($row['game_release']))->format("j M 'y");
    } else {
       $date = (new DateTime($row['game_release']))->format("M 'y");
    }
        echo"
            <tr>
              <td> ".$date." </td>
```

The reason why I need it, is because some dates are invalid 00-05-2015 for example. I use this to list games as announced, but without a confirmed release date. I realize they are invalid, but if I query for dates `BETWEEN 2015-04-00 AND 2015-04-30` they show up under April like they should.

However, in the code above, which I'm using in my search engine, a game listed as 2015-04-00 would appear as 'March '15'. Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: how are your dates currently formatted in your database ? they should be like `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: If your db's column is setup as datetime or similar, MySQL stores it as YYYY-mm-dd could be why. Just reverse your format.

Comment: @cmorrissey Purely coincidental lol talk about today's closeness award.

Comment: They are YYYY-MM-DD format in the database. I just used DD-MM-YYYY examples here out of habit (I'm Belgian). It's a date field.

Comment: a var_dump of datetime('2015-04-00') is showing object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2015-03-31 00:00:00.000000' (length=26).  This shows why you are seeing 'March 15'.   clearing php is treating the date 00 differently than how mysql is treating.

Comment: That does explain it, thanks. Any ideas on how to solve it? I've been trying several workarounds without any success...

Comment: Do you put the dates in quotes like `BETWEEN '2015-04-00' AND '2015-04-30'`? Otherwise you’ll end up with `BETWEEN 2011 AND 1981`.

Comment: Yes, they are wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this happening

Because months usually start on day 1, thus day 0 is the previous month.

> and how can I solve it?

```
else {
   $date = (new DateTime(($day+1) . "$month-$year"))->format("M 'y");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Marco Bernardini suggested add one day to the not released date and show the correct month.
If it were me.  I would not rely on empty date alone. I would add a flag_release to the database table which I would verify as 0 everytime I show the upcoming releases.

```
$date = (new DateTime($row['game_release']));
$date->modify("+1 day");
echo $date->format("M 'y");
```